# Should we put LLBL ORM entity object into the controller action method as parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ASP NET solution we are working on consists of multiple layers, user interface is developed using asp net mvc  2 web form view engine with extensively use of template editors and data annotations (recently we upgraded it to asp net mvc 3).
For instance, we have Create action in RegistrationController:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(PersonViewModel person)
        {

            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View(person);
                }
                else
                {
             var personInterface = BusinessRegister.PersonHandler.Save(person);
                    return View("Edit", personInterface);
                }

            }
            catch {

            }
        }
```

So, we have PersonViewModel which is attended to be simple data transfer object connecting information passed from browser into controller action. Further, it calls PersonHandler.Save (behind this call stay WCF service responsible for  serializing transferred object into PersonEntity (LLBL object).

The problem happened because WCF need contract so it does not know what to do with PersonViewModel (or better how to serialize it) and for that reason chief architect give a proposal to put reference directly on assembly where ORM entities are situated and change controller signature. So now our controller looks like

```
[HttpPost]       
 public ActionResult Create(PersonEntity person)
        {
….
```

I am asking you for help – is it correct doing it this way - putting ORM entity behind default model binder of mvc framework? I am not sure  this is best modeling practice -shoudn’t it be viewModel  instead so we can later use some kind of mapping to PersonEntity? Or, better, how to avoid tightly coupling here (which is obvious).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using an ORM entity class as a parameter in a controller action shoots an arrow of hard-dependency right through from the top layer of your application to your bottom layer.

I think going this route would have a very bad impact on your ability to make changes in the application.

Now you will have to reconcile any change in your entity with the HTML form that makes a POST.  That is strikingly bad, and this flies in the face of every best practice recommendation I've ever seen regarding MVC.

Comment: Thank you, I'm deeply aware this way I described above we will arrive nowhere, so already thinking about isolating working with ORM entities via separate service interfaces (perhaps repository pattern would be welcome here)?

Answer (score 1):

3 answers for the price of one:

1. Automapper ([automapper.codeplex.com](http://automapper.codeplex.com))
2. Use it
3. Love it <3

Comment: var personInterface = BusinessRegister.PersonHandler.Save(Automapper.Mapper.Map<PersonViewModel, PersonEntity>(person));

Answer (score 0):

I think it is depend on your business logic and actual needs. For simple use why not directly use Domain Entity? I do not see any reason to use ViewModel or View Object,etc. Domain Entity normally do not need to be test if only work as data container. If you have rich domain entity, I think you should create a ViewModel to do this.
If you need consider performance such as load a big list or need fetch some information cross different tables, I recommend you use View Object and manually create sql for ORM to use.

Comment: It it is for simple use, then the decision should be not to use Domain Driven Design at all.  If a class is only a "data container" than by definition it is *not* a Domain Entity.

Comment: Thank you, domain entity class has about 2000 lines of code. It is terrific expirience finding all properties  (which web form view engine render to client) in that class and putting data annotations above each one

Comment: Re qstarin most project always has some simple business logic, but that does not mean the project is not complicated. Rich Domain is good thing but it is hard to learn and control and require all team members have good knowledge on this.